# opposite of xmlParseDoc using libxml2

Tags: xml, libxml2

I am currently using libxml2 to parse a String from memory to a tree with the xmlParseDoc function. However, after I have added new nodes to the XML,using the libxml2 functions, I need to revert back to string form from the tree, similar to the  xmlSaveFormatFile function, only using strings and not actual on disk documents and I do not know the function that could do something like this. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`xmlDocDumpMemory`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlDocDumpMemory) and friends. From the documentation:

```
void xmlDocDumpMemory(xmlDocPtr cur, xmlChar **mem, int *size);
```

Dump an XML document in memory and return the #xmlChar * and it's size in bytes. It's up to the caller to free the memory with xmlFree(). The resulting byte array is zero terminated, though the last 0 is not included in the returned size.

`cur:`  the document
`mem:`  OUT: the memory pointer
`size:` OUT: the memory length